# Dig returning more A records when queried with ANY vs A

Tags: dns

While doing some research on querying DNS records, and how `dig` works, I ran into an unexpected situation that I've been unable to find an explanation for.

Executing `dig google.com a @8.8.8.8` returns a single A record (that changes between requests, but this is something I expect).

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     300 IN  A   142.251.39.110
```

Now, when I execute the (deprecated) `ANY` request `dig google.com any @8.8.8.8` it suddenly returns multiple A-records.

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     286 IN  A   142.251.31.139
google.com.     286 IN  A   142.251.31.102
google.com.     286 IN  A   142.251.31.138
google.com.     286 IN  A   142.251.31.101
google.com.     286 IN  A   142.251.31.113
google.com.     286 IN  A   142.251.31.100
- removed the other answers -
```

Why is the same nameserver returning more A-records for the `ANY` lookup vs. `A` lookup? Is there something I should change in my `A` lookup to get the same result-set?

Comment: This probably depends on the node you're using. Tried from a VPS in Japan with ANY and I get a single A record along with the other record types.

Comment: @Martheen did you target the 8.8.8.8 nameserver specifically? If I try it with 1.1.1.1 for example I do get a single record. But that doesn't really change my expectation that if multiple A records are returned for an ANY lookup, that those same records should be returned for the A lookup.

Comment: Yes, I target 8.8.8.8, Cloudflare won't respond to ANY, they will return NOTIMP, if you get a record from @1.1.1.1 I suspect your ISP actually intercept DNS requests.

Answer (score -1):

#### Why is the same nameserver returning more A-records for the `ANY` lookup?

The dig command is used as follows:

```
dig [server] [name] [type]
```

Where `[type]` – The [type](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/dns-record-types) of DNS record to retrieve. By default (or if left blank), dig uses the `A` record type.

Use the `ANY` Option to return **all** the results of the query.

This will include all the records types defined in [type](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/dns-record-types)

For more information see [How to Use Linux dig Command (DNS Lookup) {With Examples}](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-dig-command-examples)

Comment: This is incorrect and is exactly why ANY is deprecated, see: https://blog.cloudflare.com/rfc8482-saying-goodbye-to-any/

Even if it were true that it would return ALL records, even the A-request should have returned those records.